# How to make apk hard to decompile by show java app?

Tags: java, android

Please help I am new to android development I am building an android app but it gets decompile by show java app very easily I tried some other app to decompile but show java app couldn't decompile them. So my question is how to add this type of security in my app too??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ProGuard tool, it's an utility to obfuscate the code: it's still possible to do reverse engineering but it's much harder. It's also included in the Android sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Well android studio uses proguard by default so you can add this line in your gradle file to make it both optimized and hard to decompile. As a result your apk will also be smaller size.

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it before  but didn't work I think something to add in progaurd-rules.pro file but don't know what??

Comment: you only have to add classes to keep in proguardr-rules.pro. Are you sure you added minifyEnabled true while compiling ?

Comment: Yes I am sure but in rule file default is added

Comment: can you please tell me what to add in progaurd-rules.pro file

Comment: you only need to add the classes that may be stripped by proguard but usually it is empty. Adding things there won't do anything to make apk de-compilation harder.